# How to Determine if a Font is a symbol font or a text font

Tags: python, fonts, kivy, python-imaging-library

I am building a kivy app and need to include a font chooser. Since I cannot find one for kivy, I am building my own. But I cannot find a way to tell if a font is usable for me (i.e., can I use it to make a sentence as opposed to a string of symbols). I am using the Pillow ImageFont. Is there any way to descriminate between symbol and text fonts in python?

Comment: That is a common problem, even for "normal" fonts. There seems to be nothing in the current ImageFont class that suggests anything useful. I'd say, "live with it" and let the consequences be upon the user who willingly selects such a font. Who knows, they might even *want* WingDings.

Comment: I don't think it's actually possible, I've tried to find a way to do something similar in the past, and couldn't

Comment: You can check what character set is supported with something like this: https://github.com/davelab6/pyfontaine - but I know that doesn't really answer your question

Comment: @Lissy, that looks promising, but it is ony Python2. I am working in Python 3.6.

Comment: Using the font PANOSE information would be an excellent way to determine if the font is the one that you require. Unfortunately, I heard is not always added to the fonts, and when added that the info is not always correct. Besides, I'm not sure how could you extract the PANOSE info from the font... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been working on this and I am now a bit happier with my work. Still not perfect, but the following code only gives me one false positive for fonts that support text on my Ubuntu box:

```
def isValidFont(f, fontNum=0, debug=False):
    """
    Determine if a font is a valid font for displaying text

    This code makes a best guess as to whether the font supports text.
    It does this by writing a 'W' using the font, and inspecting the result.

    :param f: full path to the font file
    :param fontNum: index into the font file (for a file containing a collection of fonts)
    :param debug: If True, files will be written for each font with information useful for debugging
    :return: True if font appears to support text, False otherwise
    """

    # size of test image
    width = 40
    height = 40

    font = ImageFont.truetype(f, index=fontNum, size=height-6)
    fontName = font.getname()
    tmpImg = Image.new('1', (width,height)) #default fill is 0 (black)

    # draw a single 'W' into the test image (sized and positioned to fit inside test image)
    # this codes depends on the character drawn being a 'W'
    dr = ImageDraw.Draw(tmpImg)
    dr.text((3, 3), 'W', font=font, fill=(1))

    if debug:
        # save test image for this font
        fname = str(fontName) + '.bmp'
        tmpImg.save(fname)

    # get the data from the image as a list of 1's and 0's (one value per pixel)
    img_data = list(tmpImg.getdata())

    if debug:
        # write the image data to a file
        fname = str(fontName) + '.txt'
        fd = open(fname, mode='w')
        for row in range(height):
            fd.write(str(img_data[row*width : (row+1)*width]) + '\n')
        fd.close()

    # if the image is all black (0's), this is not a valid text font
    if sum(img_data) == 0:
        return False

    # build a simplified version of the image data
    compressedList = []
    for i in range(height):
        prev_elem = None
        thisRow = []
        for j in range(width):
            index = i*width + j
            elem = img_data[index] # this is the element at (i,j)
            if prev_elem is None:
                # first element in this row, just append to "thisRow"
                thisRow.append(elem)
                prev_elem = elem
            elif elem == prev_elem:
                # if this element is same as previous (and it's a one), just increment the value in "thisRow"
                if elem == 1:
                    thisRow[len(thisRow)-1] += 1
            else:
                # just append the element to "thisRow"
                thisRow.append(elem)
                prev_elem = elem
        # finished row #i, append it to "compressedList"
        compressedList.append(thisRow)

    # a bit more compressing
    for row in compressedList:
        # eliminate leading zeros from each row
        while len(row) > 0 and row[0] == 0:
            del row[0]

        # eliminate trailing zeros from each row
        while len(row) > 0:
            index = len(row)-1
            if row[index] == 0:
                del row[index]
            else:
                break

    # eliminate leading empty rows
    while len(compressedList[0]) == 0:
        del compressedList[0]

    # eliminate trailing empty rows
    index = len(compressedList)-1
    while len(compressedList[index]) == 0:
        del compressedList[index]
        index = len(compressedList)-1

    if debug:
        # save the compressed format
        fname = str(fontName) + '_c.txt'
        fd = open(fname, mode='w')
        for row in compressedList:
            fd.write(str(row) + '\n')
        fd.close()

    # this is where the decision is actually made
    for row in compressedList:
        if len(row) > 3: # characteristic of a 'W', a simple box will have maximum rowLen of 3
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in this stuff, but here how I see things.

When you trying to write some letter with font, renderer will use this letter's [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) to get draw instructions from font file. 3 situations possible:

1. Instruction for code point exists, but contains wrong image. For
   example, for code point `0x0041` instead of containing instructions
   to draw latin capital letter "A" font contains instruction to draw
   some emoji.
2. Instruction for code point exists and contains correct image.
3. Instruction for code point doesn't exist.

In the first case you have no options: only human (or very advanced script) can say that "this bunch of pixels contains emoji instead of letter". But this situation should be rare: this is not how (normal) people create symbol fonts.

Second case is simple: this font is ok, you can use it.

Third case is a bit more interesting. Sometimes people leave codepoint for unicode images ([for example](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode)) filled, but remove instructions for letters to decrease font file size. [ImageFont](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageFont.html) doesn't seem to have specific methods to extract info by codepoints, but it [allows us](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.PIL.ImageFont.ImageFont.getmask) to get text masks. Mask for text that can be drawn by font will have `(0, 0)` size:

```
from PIL import ImageFont


font = ImageFont.truetype("font_to_test.ttf")

mask = font.getmask('abcdefg')  # use some letters from lang you need

if mask.size == (0, 0):
    print('This is image font.')
else:
    print('This is text font.')
```

Not ideal, but does job for couple of fonts I tested.

Comment: That worked for some of the fonts, but not enough. It seems that most of the symbol fonts draw a box for any text character,  so I wrote a method to try to detect that. I create a small (10x10) 1-bit image and write a single character into it (Using Pillow). Then I do some really ugly heuristics to attempt to detect the box in the image. Seems to work, but it is such a hack and so ugly that I will not post it.